# PFC inductor calculation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, power-factor-correction

I have a question about PFC inductor calculation.
Please see the below figure.
[image]

[image]

This is my answer, but I don't know how to only let Lmin equal to Vrms, P, fs.
There is a V (output voltage) in there. I don't know how to cancel it.

[image]

Update:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133466/discussion-on-question-by-eec-pfc-inductor-calculation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duty ratio of the CCM boost PFC boost converter follows the same formula of the classical dc-dc switching cell except that the input voltage is a rectified sinusoidal waveform. The below slide shows the simple derivation:

[image]

I built many PFC examples in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468) on SMPS from 2014 and it lets me verify the above calculations are ok:

[image]

Regarding the minimum inductance, you can determine the critical inductance value below which the converter runs in DCM. The formula for the critical inductance of a boost converter is: \$\frac{(1-\frac{V_{in}}{V_{out}})V_{in}^2R_L}{2F_{sw}V_{out}^2}\$.

But you can also use the formula given by Tony, this is a classical formula for the boost converter adapted to the PFC by Joël: \$L_{min}=\frac{(\sqrt{2}V_{ac,LL})^2}{2\delta I_rF_{sw}P_{out}}(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}V_{ac,LL}}{V_{out}})\$. A 100% ripple means the converter operates in borderline operation.

Comment: HI Verbal,

Thanks.  It is very clear to explain the min inductor, but I am still confused about why my answer is wrong. 
The system said the vo can't be shown in the equation only the Vrms, P, fs can show in the equation. 
Do you think the system has a problem?

Comment: Hello, if you like the answer, please be so kind to validate it, thanks. Well, \$V_{out}\$ is the regulated voltage so it's well known and you can always replace it by \$\sqrt{PR}\$ but it would only bring confusion to the expression. Is this for a Coursera class?

Comment: HI Verbal,
Yes, this is for a Coursera class.

Comment: I recognized a schematic diagram from Fundamentals of Power Electronics : )

Comment: Yes, I can learn from the basics haha. 
But the exam is difficult to pass, I still can get right answer, after I type your answer.

Comment: Tell Bob I gave you the answer : )

Answer (score 0):

[If I rely on 2014 research alone from Joel Turchi .](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/HBD853-D.PDF)  But Chris who drops in now and again has updated this in his latest book after years of research at the same onsemi location, I presume, in france.

[image]

[Chris's book](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm)  He discusses some gotcha's [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/481195/improving-flyback-dcm-peak-power-using-ccm) , but I'll let you do the research. He has the answers.

Note the curve above has a tradeoff with the minimum L near 500 uH 50% ripple and the preferrred input ripple of 25% then L is reduced by the inverse  of % ripple, so half the ripple at twice the L.

Comment: Yes Tony, Joël and I were in Toulouse (France) developing PWM controllers for ac-dc and dc-dc converters.

Comment: HI Tony, 

I will read the book.